# How can i get the response of a server using cURL with php?

Tags: php, xml, curl, response

I have a sender script and a receiver script. The sender sends an xml file , while the receiver gets it and stores it in the database.

The sender looks like this :

```
$xml = file_get_contents("data.xml");

  // We send XML via CURL using POST with a http header of text/xml.
  $ch = curl_init();
  // set URL and other appropriate options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/iPM/receiver.php");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://localhost/iPM/receiver.php');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo "Result = ".$ch_result;
  curl_close($ch);
```

and the receiver :

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');

parsing the xml - storing to database
etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc
```

I need when i run the sender script , to get back a response from the receiver that everything was ok and the xml file was received. I believed that i would see that with this line of code , in my code :  `echo "Result = ".$ch_result;`  but the only thing i see printed is `Result =` .

So what am i doing wrong? What should i add on my sender/receiver to have a response back?

Comment: What happens if you do a "view source" ?

Comment: Stupid question, but are you actually echoing anything in the receiver script? If so, what?

Comment: What do you mean? View the page source? Its the same only Result =

Comment: No i am not echoing anything. I just save the xml in the database using PDO. Do i need to actually echo the response?? and if yes how do i do that?

Comment: Yes, you need to output result if you wish to view it in sender. You can do that with `echo`, `print` or `exit()`.

Comment: If you have `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` set to 1, `curl_exec()` returns the response, so if you want it to actually echo anything, you have to echo something in your receiver script. Just try putting `die('working');` at the beginning of the receiver script and you should then see the output `Result = working`. Then go from there.

Comment: i tried the echo("working") and works fine. Whats the difference with die() ? Also why i dont get automatically the 200 response , or any other http status code?

Comment: try to set  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); to 1, and show us the headers. Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following lines:

```
$ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "Result = " . $ch_result;
```

with the following lines and see if it works:

```
$ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
$ch_header = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo "Status : " . $ch_header['http_code'] . "<br />";
echo "Result = " . $ch_result;
```

The [`curl_getinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) return basic information about the request and the `http_code` variable returns the response code 200,404 etc. You can then check for the code and parse it as per your requirements.

Hope it helps.